# HTML5 Audio m4a

Tags: jquery, html, audio, m4a

Is it possible to play m4a music files using html5 audio? If that is not possible do you know of any flash player that can play m4a outside JWPlayer, I need a free one.

Answer (score 0):

Any Flash player should be able to play MP4 content - this capability is coded into Flash, not the player product built on top of it.

[JPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) is a nice free player that uses HTML5 where it can, and falls back on Flash when it can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Soundmanager2 which can use Flash fallback if HTML5 does not natively support M4A.

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

M4A should be supported by the browsers from companies who support MPEG-4 video and are the licensees of MPEG4-LA patents (Microsoft, Apple).