# How to play a .mp3 or .m4a audio on a webpage and show the embedded album art at the same time? (using Javascript, HTML5, or Flash)

Tags: javascript, flash, html, audio-streaming, m4a

There are ways to play a `.m4a` audio on a webpage [using jPlayer or SoundManager2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538215/html5-audio-m4a), but it seems that they will not show the cover art (automatically for each song).

Is there a way to automatically play the `.m4a` audio, as well as showing the cover art on a webpage, using Javascript, HTML5, or Flash?  I think possibly for many `.m4a`, the cover art picture is already embedded in the `.m4a` file, as downloaded from the iTunes store.  Or in the event that no cover art is there, is there a way to dynamically pull one?   (Note: this is for any number of `.m4a` files automatically, such as 2, or 3, rather than just tailoring for one song.  So this is similar to [Yahoo Mediaplayer](http://developer.yahoo.com/mediaplayer/) or [Yahoo Webplayer](http://webplayer.yahoo.com/)... the new one supports album art, but seems to only support one static image)

Answer (score 0):

http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/ xspf player shows artist and album info, it needs xspf playlist, but not sure if it supports m4a format.

Comment: I tried both mp3 and m4a -- the mp3 worked, but m4a didn't.  Also, from http://www.xspf.org/quickstart/ it seems that the album art are static images, not automatically extracted from the file.  When you are not sure about your answer by so many parameters, post it as a comment.  If you post it as an answer, people will not look at the question any more because they think "it is solved"

Comment: A solved question would look different. I use it for playing mp3s and displaying artist album image etc. I am sorry it did not work enough for you. If you want me to delete my answer because it did not solve your problem let me know. And good luck on extracting image from file using javascript or html5 or flash.

Comment: are you displaying images that are static?  It is not inconceivable to display the album art that is already part of the file.

Comment: Yes static images. I guess it would be hard to extrace images by html5 or javascript..probably imposdible. May be flash would be able to do that or some server side code

Comment: Why not tag "flash" too so flash expert can get hold of this question.

Comment: I think unless HTML5 or the browser has something to show the album art.  I think one of the reasons iTunes or iPod is quite lovely is that you can see the album art and even flip through the albums.  If we can have dynamically changing album art, that can be quite attractive.  (yup, i removed the tag `audio` and added the tag `flash` coz it was full list of tags)

Answer (score 0):

Extract the cover art from the file first, server-side.  Don't leave it up to the player.

There are many ways to do this.  If  you are hosting on Windows, you can use the [MediaInfo DLL](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14949).

Comment: yeah, i don't want to extract the album art like that.  the key is, if you have 8 songs, and all with different album arts embedded in the file, why not let the player show it automatically?  Why show the art and then cut it out and then mess with all the 8 pictures yourself?  What if you add or remove a song, then it is total mess.

Comment: @動靜能量, How is it a total mess?  Why is it a problem when you add/remove a song?  A very simple database will do just fine.

Comment: if the album art is embedded in the `.m4a` file, then why manually show it on the PC, cut it out, save the file, upload it to the server?  And to even use a database?

Comment: @動靜能量, It is the easiest, and fastest solution.  Plus, you may want to use that album art again elsewhere, such as in a catalog.  I don't understand why this is so hard.  If you could explain it, I could help you.  Instead, you answer my questions with questions, which isn't helping your situation.

Answer (score 0):

jPlayer has a poster property which can be set when you setMedia, or work with your playlist using the jPlayer playlist plugin.

Granted the jPlayer poster is a static image you provide, it will probably be the easiest route.  However..

Embedded album art I do believe is contained within ID3v1, ID3v2 comments or Vorbis comments depending on the media format your using and when it was created.  There is a JavaScript library for reading ID3 data from media files https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader